# how to save configuration layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application where the main layout is loaded from xml file.

**The layout loaded is :**

A **relative layout** with 5 button. When user click on the button appear a menu, where he can choose a type of view. After choosing view, button will invisible and appears chosen view.

**After restarting** the application , system load default layout ( relative layout with 5 button).
I want that when the application restart the system load the last selected layout.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using Shared Preferences in Android: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

You may store a boolean value to track the state of the layout (whether it is the RelativeLayout with 5 Buttons, or the View chosen state with 4 Buttons). This way when you load the activity, you can first check this flag to determine which layout you want to load. You can also use the preference such that you do not need to initialize this flag variable, but instead you can use a default value.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    public enum ViewState {
        NO_CLICK, VIEW_A, VIEW_B, ...
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       int currentView = settings.getInt("viewClicked", NO_CLICK);

       switch(currentView)
       {
           case VIEW_A: // Load the view if button A was clicked
               loadViewA();
               break;
           case VIEW_B: // Load the view if button B was clicked
               loadViewB();
               break;
           ...
           case NO_CLICK: // Load the RelativeLayout with 5 Buttons
           default:
               loadDefaultView();
               break;
       }
    }
```

And in your OnClickListener for the button A:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

  ...

  // Get the settings
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putInt("viewClicked", VIEW_A);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();

  // Load the view
  loadViewA();
}
```

The other onClick() method for the other buttons could be implemented similarly.

**Edit:** Updated to use an integer rather than a boolean

Comment: the problem is different, i have a layout with 5 button, if the user click on the button-a , appear a menu : example  choose viewa/viewb/viewc , if the user choose view a , the button-a begin invisible and appear view a. when the application restart i want to load a layout with 4 button and view a. i insert by code runtime the button A in the layout so i dont have any layout called clickedLayout

Comment: You should still be able to apply the idea behind the answer I posted. Rather than using/storing the preference as a boolean, you could store it as an integer. This integer will now represent which of the buttons was clicked, or what the last state of the view truly was. If you factor out your dynamic code that is currently creating the new layout, you could then call it in the overloaded onCreate() or onResume() after checking this integer.

Comment: can i rappresent with the integer: 0 for default button,1 view a,2 view b,3 view c ... its ok now ? thanks

Comment: the user can click all the button, so i have to save 5 integer ok ?

Comment: Yes, you would most likely want to use 6 integers. 5 for all of the buttons, and 1 for the state before the buttons were pressed.

Comment: the last answer, if i want to include in the menu the option "load default layout" , can i manage when the user click on it ? on first i have to delete the shared pref ( the method clear on it) and after have i to restart the activity ? if yes can i do the restart ? very thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, you can also have a menu to load the default layout. You would not need to delete the shared preference, nor restart the activity. Instead, you could have another function that is called to load the default view after you select it from the menu. The code would be very similar to the onClick() code I provided but instead of storing VIEW_A, you store NO_CLICK, then you could call your loadDefaultView() method.

Comment: but if i dont delete preference when i restart the activity there another time the layout edited

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean here... can you clarify? If you only wanted the view to be persistent for the activity lifecycle, then no preferences are even needed and you can just use member variables for the Activity. If you want the selected view to stay until the user selects otherwise from another menu, then my previous comment should work.

Comment: i want that the view that the user insert begin persinstent, so when re-execute application he find the last layout, but he has also have the possibility to delete the edit and return to the initial state ( 5 button add) with the option "reset default layout"

Comment: Alright, so it sounds like preferences are indeed the way to go. If you delete the preference, then the user will **not** be able to return to his last state. If you want them to be able to return to the initial state, you can either add to the options menu, or add another button for this. When that is selected, re-save the preference with the NO_CLICK state, and it should then remain in that way until they click another button.

Comment: If this completely answered your question and was the best answer, please mark this answer as such. Thank you.